# How does DNS Resolution work for protocols and ports?

Tags: c++, http, https, dns, port

I am new to this so I wanted to ask some clarifying questions.
I am clear on the path that a query can take for name resolution on dns servers.

Where I get confused is how does this work when you specify a port or a protocol and are trying to resolve a name programmatically?

For example using Boost Beast in C++

```
// Look up the domain name
auto const results = resolver.resolve(host, port);
```

Would I have to know in advance whether that port is using http or https and rely on conventions, 80 for http, 443 for https? Can a port use both protocols so the protocol has to be specified too?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: DNS normally uses port 53 (usually UDP, but also TCP). The messages on the wire use the protocol defined in RFCs 1034 and 1035, which isn't HTTP (nor is it very similar).

Comment: Port numbers are not resolved by DNS, only hostnames are. The whole purpose of DNS is to [resovle a hostname to an IP address](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/), that's all.  However, some APIs allow human-readable aliases to be used in place of well-known port numbers, for example `http` for 80, `https` for 443, `ftp` for 21, etc, so those would have to be resolved as well (but not by the DNS system).